# Oracle Database - Recursive sum?

Tags: oracle, sum, recursive

I have an Oracle db and a table and I'd want to sum the VAL column until I have the value in column SUMM 100 and the difference in column DIF - as in this example:

```
ID VAL  SUMM    DIF
1   40  40      0
2   20  60      0
3   30  90      0
4   15  100     5
5   22  0       27
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: How is `diff` calculated? The `summ` column is easy: `sum(val) over (order by id)`

Comment: from the the difference afther the summ reach 100